# I want to sort 3 dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following array :

```
$inboxMessages = array(
    105775 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 85,
            'thread_id' => 105775,
            'message' => "hello",
            'created_at' => "May 20, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432118191,
            'sender_id' => 13,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 70,
            'thread_id' => 105775,
            'message' => "hii",
            'created_at' => "May 19, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432021227,
            'sender_id' => 13,
        )
    ),
    224199 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 88,
            'thread_id' => 224199,
            'message' => "yessss...",
            'created_at' => "May 20, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432306513,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        1 => array( //index is thread_id
            'id' => 75,
            'thread_id' => 224199,
            'message' => "hellowwww...",
            'created_at' => "May 19, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432021227,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        )
    ),
    107917 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 56,
            'thread_id' => 107917,
            'message' => "how r u??",
            'created_at' => "May 16, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1431792155,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 30,
            'thread_id' => 107917,
            'message' => "hi.. i m fine.",
            'created_at' => "May 6, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1430920006,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 30,
            'thread_id' => 107917,
            'message' => "hi!!!!..how r u??",
            'created_at' => "May 6, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1430920006,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        )
    ),
    378552 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 108,
            'thread_id' => 378552,
            'message' => "hi",
            'created_at' => "May 29, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432906923,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 107,
            'thread_id' => 378552,
            'message' => "hi.",
            'created_at' => "May 29, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432903194,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        )
    )
);
```

**So i need Output like this :**

```
$inboxMessages = array(
    378552 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 108,
            'thread_id' => 378552,
            'message' => "hi",
            'created_at' => "May 29, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432906923,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 107,
            'thread_id' => 378552,
            'message' => "hi.",
            'created_at' => "May 29, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432903194,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        )
    ),
    224199 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 88,
            'thread_id' => 224199,
            'message' => "yessss...",
            'created_at' => "May 20, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432306513,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        1 => array( //index is thread_id
            'id' => 75,
            'thread_id' => 224199,
            'message' => "hellowwww...",
            'created_at' => "May 19, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432021227,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        )
    ),
    105775 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 85,
            'thread_id' => 105775,
            'message' => "hello",
            'created_at' => "May 20, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432118191,
            'sender_id' => 13,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 70,
            'thread_id' => 105775,
            'message' => "hii",
            'created_at' => "May 19, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1432021227,
            'sender_id' => 13,
        )
    ),
    107917 => array( //index is thread_id
        0 => array(
            'id' => 56,
            'thread_id' => 107917,
            'message' => "how r u??",
            'created_at' => "May 16, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1431792155,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => 30,
            'thread_id' => 107917,
            'message' => "hi.. i m fine.",
            'created_at' => "May 6, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1430920006,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        ),
        2 => array(
            'id' => 30,
            'thread_id' => 107917,
            'message' => "hi!!!!..how r u??",
            'created_at' => "May 6, 2015",
            'datetime' => 1430920006,
            'sender_id' => 14,
        )
    ),

);
```

I want to sort main array by value of `datetime` sub array of `thread_id`.

In array of `thread_id` is already sorting.

So i just want to sort main array by `thread_id`'s sub array.

I need recent datetime is top on array

**I tried so far And its works for me:**

```
function comp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0]->datetime == $b[0]->datetime) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return $a[0]->datetime > $b[0]->datetime ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($inboxMessages, "comp");
```

And also try with message `id` :

```
function comp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0]->id == $b[0]->id) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return $a[0]->id > $b[0]->id ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($inboxMessages, "comp");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) as follows to achieve the following format

```
function comp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0]['datetime'] == $b[0]['datetime']) {
        return 0;
    } return $a[0]['datetime'] > $b[0]['datetime'] ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($inboxMessages, "comp");
```

[**Check Demo**](https://eval.in/372826)

Comment: Its working for me @kupendra [**Check Demo**](https://eval.in/372826) it results as you have shown within your expected output

Comment: Are you getting any errors or else or post your original array

Comment: Are you sure that you have placed code as shown within example or demo.

Comment: Update your question what you have tried with the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Use `uasort`

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[0]['datetime'] == $b[0]['datetime']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[0]['datetime'] < $b[0]['datetime']) ? 1 : -1;
}
uasort($inboxMessages, "cmp");
```

Depending on PHP version, you can specify "cmp" as an anonymous function. Also keep in mind this method relies on the fact that each thread has at least one message in it.